# Print A to Z according to user's input: 1=A, 2=B, etc

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to print characters from A to Z depending on the user's input.
If the input is `1` then print `A`, if the input is `2` then print `B`, and so on.

I tried using a `for` loop as below, but wasn't able to achieve what I want.

```
for i in {a..z}
do
  echo $i
done
```

How can I use a loop or another approach to get the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
read i
a=(0 {A..Z})
echo ${a[$i]}
```

As arrays are zero-indexed, I simply put a `0` in front, so the array will be `0 A B C ...`. Otherwise you would get `0`→`A`, `1`→`B`, ...

Comment: thanks for your helps.

Comment: now i trying reverse means...input A =1 or B=2 and so on  what should i do changes in given script

Comment: input A  and expected output is 1

Comment: i tried this bot face error 'A+' : not a valid identifier. write full script

Comment: n={1..26}  how to store this in array for access later by index

Comment: See the `(...)` around  the `{...}`, that makes it an array.